# AutoMapper - handle removed items in mapped collections

Tags: c#, orm, automapper

Lets say I have the following classes:

```
//pseudo code

OrderDTO
    int Id
    List<DetailDTO> Details

DetailDTO
    int Id
    ..other props

Order
    int Id
    List<Detail> Details

Detail
    int Id
    ..other props
```

Lets say I also have the following mapping code:

```
OrderDTO dto = new .....
Order existingOrder = GetExistingOrder(...);
Mapper.Map<OrderDTO,Order>(dto,existingOrder);
```

This way, the state of the DTO are transfered to the existing order entity.

Now to the actual question.
Lets say that the dto contains *less* details than the entity.
that is, some details have been removed.
can I somehow find what details was removed in the AutoMapper mapping?
**I would like the mapping to execute some extra actions if items are removed from the entity.details collection.**

Can this be done or do I have to handle that outside the mapping?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to instruct AM to do this, but it will soon become more complex and obscure than just doing it in straightforward code. Usually AM is great for mapping _to_ DTO's, less for mapping back to entities.

Comment: Yes, that is my impression also, I just wanted to do my research so I didn't lie in my blogpost about just that http://rogeralsing.com/2013/12/01/why-mapping-dtos-to-entities-using-automapper-and-entityframework-is-horrible/

Comment: You're making some good points there. And you answered your own question, didn't you?